# How much credence can you give to human cognitive studies using mice?

Tags: neuroscience, study-cognitive-sciences, visual-memory

This question is concerning the question, [How does the brain’s visual memory work?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20688/how-does-the-brain-s-visual-memory-work) and the Neuroscience News ([2020](https://neurosciencenews.com/updating-mechanism-false-memory-16438/)) article linked in [an answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/27128/7604), talking about false memories.

I have discussed false memories in answers to [PTSD based on false memories](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/9254/ptsd-based-on-false-memories) and [Can people improve their memory by training themselves to recall previously forgotten memories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/can-people-improve-their-memory-by-training-themselves-to-recall-previously-forg) and the article Neuroscience News is talking about ([Zinn, et al. 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cub.2020.04.040)) talks of the possibility of altering false memories,

> the potential of updating to modify the contextual content of memory suggests a novel approach to exposure therapy

which in a sense, to me, is daft as you are potentially creating a new false memory.

Anyway, on the subject of Zinn, et al (2020), I am not completely convinced by the article in Neuroscience News talking about a study using mice.

> While these findings come from studies in mice, this research is likely to apply across many animals with developed brains, including other mammals and humans. They might also tie in with dementias, where the main memory-related problem is an apparent inability to form accurate new memories.

Being from a psychology background and not neuroscience, I understand there are ethics involved with studying humans in this way, but how do we know the same effects will in fact happen with humans?  Plus, surely you cannot actually study visual memory with mice as you cannot communicate with them.

Has it been demonstrated in any scientific way that mice remember things in the same way as humans?

### References

Neuroscience News (2020). Brain’s ‘updating mechanisms’ may create false memories https://neurosciencenews.com/updating-mechanism-false-memory-16438/

Zinn, R., Leake, J., Krasne, F. B., Corbit, L. H., Fanselow, M. S., & Vissel, B. (2020). Maladaptive properties of context-impoverished memories. *Current Biology, 30*(12), 2300-2311. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cub.2020.04.040